# Xamarin forms dragging completed event

Tags: xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I'm using Drag gesture recognizer to move elemens between different elements in xamarin forms. When draggig starts, I hide Element via IsVisible propery to indicate that it has been temporary removed from initial collection.

Now I need to know when it is released outside the views with drop gesture recognizers to return it's visibility. But it seems there is no "drag completed" events.
If I set drop recognizer for entire page, I still can drop it inside top bar with time, battery and notifications, and it will dissapea.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my bad. There is DropCompletedCommand and corresponding event in DragGestureRecognizer. It works even if element was dropped outside element with drop recognizer

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could  accept this answer which may help others with same issue, Here is official documentation for [Add drag and drop gesture recognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop).